# Java String validation via blacklist

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to write a simple validator to throw an exception if a String contains "illegal characters", specifically:

> ~, @, +, % and |

I'm searching for the cleanest way of doing this, and was hoping that there was a way to define a "blacklist" regex that might look something like:

```
String blacklist = "~@+%|";
String toValidate = getInputFromUser();

if(toValidate.matches(blacklist))
    throw new RuntimeException("Illegal characters found!");
```

However I know that the regex is incorrect. Am I heading in the right direction or am I way off base (i.e. is there a much simpler solution)? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regex should be `^.*[~@+%|].*$`

---

Alternatively you can use `[~@+%|]` with `find` method instead of `matches`

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking a clear and concise way to do it I wouldn't use regexp, as it's API in Java tends to get messy. Apache `commons-lang` has `StringUtils.containsAny("text","blacklisted");`. It's usually a good library to include anyways as it complements Java with much more than couple of string utilities.